# How to randomize array with some condition with php?

Tags: php

I have an ini file like,

```
[question_1]
qus="what is a?"
mark="5"
[question_2]
qus="what is b?"
mark="4"
[question_3]
qus="what is c?"
mark="3"
[question_4]
qus="what is d?"
mark="2"
[question_5]
qus="what is e?"
mark="2"
..........
..........
```

Here i have about 100 questions. and i need to make a function so that, i can get randomized questions each time with some total marks. like this

```
function questions ($ini_location, $total_marks)
{
$question_conf=parse_ini_file($ini_location,true);
//here is the code
}
print_r(questions ('location/of/ini/file', 100));
```

Here 100 is the total marks(addition of all marks of questions, which will be selected by the function) and 'location/of/ini/file' is the location of that ini.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can use a random function generator and mod it by 100.

The function would return a random number from 0 to 99 to access an index in your array. You just have to keep track of what index have been access... or pop the question out and mod it by one less. This wouldn't be an array anymore I guess. I guess that would work.

I don't understand what total mark is...

Comment: total mark is the addition of all marks of questions, which will be selected by the function.